# References of derived objects are invalid

Tags: clearcase

there are some derived objects with references to a view. However, referenced view does not have that derived object.

*Is there a way to delete those derived objects (DO) with invalid/unused references?*

(I believe that the cause of the problem is deleted views. We had views that had problems, and had to force remove them (using uuid). Then we created new views with the same name. Now, a DO has a reference to a view (I cant see the uuid) but DO is not used in that view. I suspect that the referenced view is the old one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the slow solution I found: I listed all DOs in each vob (`cleartool lsdo -recurse`), then listed all used DOs in views (`cleartool lsprivate -do`). Then I listed the ones that are not in the second list. I wrote an `rmdo` script for those items.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a deleted view, you can delete all references to that view with:

```
cleartool rmview -vob /vobs/MyVob -force -uuid 3c2ed44a.eda842f1.a7f8.73:09:e2:c9:12:ac
```

Replace /vobs/MyVob by the Vob tag where the view is used.
And replace 3c2ed44a.eda842f1.a7f8.73:09:e2:c9:12:ac by the old deleted view uuid.

You can  find that uuid with:

```
cleartool descr -l vob:/vobs/MyVob
```

That follows "[How to remove checked-out references of a view from a VOB](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-remove-checked-out-references-view-vob)".

However, if you mention "We had views that had problems, and had to force remove them (using uuid).", that `cleartool rmview` command might not be enough to un-reference those DO's (Derived Objects).

There was an [old issue for ClearCase 7 about that](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PK38852).

That approach (`rmview --force --uuid` is confirmed with "[About `rgy_getuuid_by_uuid` failed errors](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/about-rgygetuuidbyuuid-failed-errors)":

> For example, `clearmake` may provide the following warning when attempting to access a view that no longer exists, but had sharable Derived Objects:
>
> ```
> clearmake: Warning: View "ccsvr:c:\ccstg\views\tempview2.vws" unavailable -
> This process will not contact the view again for 60 minutes.
> ```
>
> If the view was removed or is inaccessible, references to the view have to be removed with the `cleartool rmview -uuid` command.
> This command will remove all references to a given view in all mounted VOBs (review to [technote 1122515](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-remove-checked-out-references-view-vob) for more details):

Again, a `rmview --uuid` is shown there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From "cleartool lsdo -long" command, I get a reference to a view with view path; something like \share\viewstore\abc_view.vws. Sometime ago, this view is deleted and another view is created with same name and path. From lsdo command, I cannot see the uuid of referenced view, only path is shown. I tried ccase_fmt combinations to see the uuid, but couldn't find anything. When I set abc_view (later created view), the derived file is not being used there.

Comment: Normally, I use rmview to remove a view. However if there is a problem with viewstore, I use "cleartool rmview -force -avobs -uuid xxx.xxx.xx.xx" command, and use "cleartool rmtag -view abc_view" if tag is still there. I don't remember how did I delete abc_view in the past.

Comment: @yusuf Maybe by looking the [registry](https://techpubs.jurassic.nl/manuals/0630/admin/ClrC_AG/sgi_html/ch18.html), you can find the uuid of the deleted view, and perform the `cleartool rmview -force -avobs -uuid xxx.xxx.xx.xx` command

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that. I regularly use rgy_check and delete problems listed there.